# How spoof referrer with curl and php?

Tags: php, curl

I need a simple full php + curl code to spoof referrer, I tried some other but not working, last one I checked is this

```
function doMagic($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Pragma: ";

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return $html;
}
```

please make it so I can enter target url via post method if possible

EDIT- above giving me error https://s9.postimg.cc/uhk87o2rz/image.png

Comment: the example you posted looks fine to me I don't see a problem with it.
The only thing is that the referer is always set to facebook.com

Comment: I'm getting text "curl error:" with target site on top of page, how  can i replace facebook.com with custom referrer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With the **CURLOPT_REFERER** option, which you had already made use of.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "your referer website");
```

[**EDIT**]
I don't think that website can find referer of your localhost website.

**Try this on Google Chrome Browser**

In the Developer Tools, go to the Network view (if it wasn't open when you loaded the page, you'll need to reload to get it populated).
Click on the main page request -- it should be at the top of the list.
When you click, the right pane will probably show the HTML for it.
Click on the "Headers" tab on the right side.
The Referer is shown in the list of Request Headers.

Comment: I'm getting error with above code please post full php code to use

Comment: Just set any referrer website like this `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com/bot.html"); `

Comment: see here http://s9.postimg.org/uhk87o2rz/image.png

Comment: i already tested with blogger and some other sites spoofing referrer is working but there is always text on each page "curl error:"

Comment: @golumolu, Remove this line `echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($curl);` from your code.

Comment: thanks @Shankar Damodaran it OK now, can you help in tinybox 2 popup box?

Comment: Can i use php variable insteed of facebook.com as referrer, i want to get referrer site from database