# Print/echo image after retrieving it using curl like this:

Tags: image, curl

I'm testing this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294244/how-spoof-referrer-with-curl-and-php) and it seems to work, but it doesn't show an image but the code of the image.

I'm trying changing headers params with no luck, any idea?

Comment: Which headers did you set? And use your browsers debugging tool to see the actual headers sent .... Should make this quite obvious

Comment: header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

Answer (score 0):

really basic fault :)

You must put header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); at the very top of the file.